# Read POST data from client in an ASHX file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, httphandler

I need to post form data using jQuery AJAX.

the form is made up of some input text, i.e.: firstname, lastname, age

I post to an ASHX file and I'd like to read them directly like a Request.Form["firstname"] and not by building a class, serialize object etc... like is generally done with JSON post

is it possible to that?

Comment: Yes it is possible, use your browsers debugging tools and watch what is sent...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of your use case to consider this approach but here is how you could achieve it. In the **ProcessRequest** method of the Handler class in the ashx code behind file,

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) { 
var formData = context.Request.Form; // Get the form object from the current HTTP request.

foreach(var formVariable in formData)
  {
    var value = formData[formVariable];
  }
}
```

I hope this would help in your case!